# Catel.ModelAttribute causes memory leak?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, memory-leaks, catel

We're using Catel Framework 3.9 (cannot upgrade to newer version because we're in production). I recently noticed that when opening a ViewModel multiple times, the ViewModel stays in memory.
I tracked the issue down to one DTO that was bound to the View and was using the `[Model]` attribute. The DTO inherits the `Catel.ModelBase` so it automatically implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Also all properties are DependencyProperties (using Catel's `RegisterProperty` method).

I tried removing the bindings from the XAML, but it didn't help. When I removed the `[Model]` attribute from the ViewModel's property, the ViewModel no longer stayed in memory.

I used the JetBrains dotTrace to profile the memory usage and it showed that `Catel.Data.PropertyBag` reserves the memory and doesn't seem to release it if the property uses the `[Model]` attribute. See the attached image: on the left you can see that there are 14 instances of the ViewModel in memory.

Has anyone been able to reproduce the issue? What else can be done if we cannot use the [Model] attribute anymore? Has the issue been addressed in the Catel 4.0+?

[image: dotMemory capture]

Comment: The ChangeNotificationWrapper is somehow not clearing up, otherwise the collection would have been released. Please report an issue at http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker if you can reproduce in latest stable (4.4).